# How do I animate a rotation with 3D cursor as pivot point?

Tags: animation, keyframes

I am trying to animate a bell swinging. I've managed to make it rotate from side to side using keyframes, but I want it to rotate with the 3D cursor as its pivot point. How do I do that?

1. https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8SpE.jpg

[image]

2. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vs8NF.jpg

[image]

As is shown in the pictures, the small "top piece" of the bell isn't fixed to the 3D cursor; it is not its pivot point; and that is my problem.

Comment: put in keyframes for rotation and location

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add images that might help us understand what you have done and your scene and settings. ( to learn how to post images [read this link:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The object's position is based on the rotation and location of its *origin.* When you change an object's rotation property, the origin's rotation is changed and the entire mesh is rotated around that point.

If the origin is somewhere in the middle of the object, and you apply rotation keyframes to it, this happens.

[image: wrong rotation]

But since you want your bell to rotate about a point near its top, you just need to move the object's origin to the rotation point, resulting in something like this:

[image]

To move the origin, you can move your 3D cursor to the point where you want the origin, select the object, right-click, and go to *Set Origin* > *Origin to 3D Cursor*.

Alternatively, while in *Object mode*, you can go to the *Active Tool and Workspace Settings* tab and under *Options* > *Transform* > *Affect only*, select *Origins*.

[image: Menu]

This will cause any transformations you do to only affect the object's origin, allowing you to move it to the top of your bell.

Another method to change an object's pivot point in animations is to create an *Empty Axis* at the desired pivot point, parent the object (your bell in this case), to the empty, and animate the axis instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This solved my problem.